# function of derivative of a function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I know a similar question is answered somewhere, but it doesn't work for my case for some reason. I have the following problem in Mathematica. I want to compute f[h[x]]= x^2 + D[h[x],x]. Here, h[x] can be some function of x, say Sin[x]. I have written the following code in Mathematica,

```
SetAttributes[{f, D}, HoldAll]
f[h_, x_] := x^2 + D[h[x], x]
h := Sin[x]
```

But then the output of

```
f[h, 10]
```

is an error "General::ivar: 10 is not a valid variable."

Any better way of doing the composition of functions in Mathematica?

- Sarah

Comment: @b.gatessucks, Thanks. But I was aiming for some generic function rather than only Sin. In particular, the actual h[x] in my case is a quite complicated function.

Comment: You mean, f[h[#] &, x_] := x^2 + D[h[x], x]
h[x_] := Sin[x] ? In that case, f[h[10], 10] just returns f[h[10], 10].

Answer (score 2):

You can define :

```
f2[h_, x_] := x^2 + Derivative[1][h][x]
```

Then :

```
(* Specific function, generic x *)
h1[x_] = Sin[x];
f2[h1, x]
(* x^2 + Cos[x] *)     

(* Generic function, numeric x *)
f2[h, 10]
(* 100 + Derivative[1][h][10]*)

(* Generic function, generic x *)
f2[g, x]
(* x^2 + Derivative[1][g][x] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of `Derivative` is that it can derivative at a particular value or derivative in general. In most cases, you can define a function like this

```
myD[f_, lst_List, x0_List] := Derivative[Sequence @@ lst][f][Sequence @@ x0]
```

For example, if the function is defined as

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[Cos[x + y]]
```

then `myD[f, {1, 1}, {a, b}]` gives

> -Cos[a + b] Cos[Cos[a + b]] - Sin[a + b]^2 Sin[Cos[a + b]]

However, the cons is you can't put the whole function body into `myD`, i.e. Sin[Cos[x + y]] in this case. `myD[Sin[Cos[x + y]], {1, 1}, {a, b}]` will not work as expected. In other words, you have to define the function first, and then put this function without parameters into `myD`.

Another option is to use `D` with `ReplaceAll`.

```
myD2[f_, {x_Symbol, n_Integer /; n > 0}] := D[f, {x, n}];    
myD2[f_, {x_Symbol, a_, n_Integer /; n > 0}] := D[f, {x, n}] /. x -> a;
```

Conversely, you have to put the function with parameters into `myD2`:

```
myD2[f[x, y], {y, 1}]
```

returns

> -Cos[Cos[x + y]] Sin[x + y]

as expected. While, `myD2[f, {y, 1}]` gives `0`.

I myself prefer the latter option, because it can also differentiate the function body directly.

```
myD2[Sin[Cos[x + y]], {y, 1}]
```

will also give `-Cos[Cos[x + y]] Sin[x + y]`.

To use `Derivative`, one have to extract the function without parameters first, then `Derivative` on it, then act them onto the parameters. That's too difficult and complicate for me.